# Velodyne 64 to 32

Tags: velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm new here so forgive me. I understand there is some Velodyne 64 data capture and packet reading code here some where (where though?). I'd like to find it and modify it for the Velodyne 32. Is that possible?
I haven't ready any of the site rules, etc. yet.
JAF

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10792/velodyne-64-to-32/) by [JAF](https://answers.ros.org/users/919/jaf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-08-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's the first link, when you google: velodyne ROS.

The license says BSD, so you can use and modify the code.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3